# Aliased fonts in Picasa for OS X

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, picasa

I just installed Picasa on Mountain Lion, but the fonts are really ugly and aliased:

[image]

This is a MacBook Pro with Retina display, if that makes a difference.
Is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with many apps on the retina Macbook Pro. We'll just have to wait until Google updates Picasa for the high-resolution display. There is a discussion about this on Google's [Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/NQ1pSYdB7dE).

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks for the info!